# magnetic heading on iPod Touch 4g

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ipod-touch

[CLLocationManager headingAvailable] returns NO on my iPod Touch 4, but I have an app on the device that determines magnetic heading with location services turned off.
Is there any other way to get the heading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found! CoreMotion is the answer.
Heading on iPod 4 is not available through CLLocationManager, but we still can read magnetometer data using CoreMotion framework